# Proof that a critical point found by Lagrange multipliers method can't if set is closed and bounded be a saddle point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Can you provide a proof or explanation as to why a critical point found using the Lagrange multipliers method cannot be a saddle point if the set is both closed and bounded?

I've so a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4205667/1111283) explaining that it can't but I'm interested in proof.

Comment: It can be a saddle. But if you are on a smooth enough closed and bounded surface then one of the critical points has to be a max and another has to be a min. But there could be another one that is a saddle.

Comment: Can you prove that?

Comment: Prove what? The maximum value theorem guarantees that a continuous function on a compact (closed and bounded) set in $\Bbb R^n$ must take on its maximum and minimum. Some functions must have saddle points, but others do not.

Comment: The one thing that there is to prove is that the max and min is actually at a critical point, but this is really what the Lagrange multiplier theory says, that a critical point is necessary but not sufficient for optimality (except for corners etc.)